# In the Google Places AutoComplete Address i am Getting the Predictions but not saved in the Text Box

Tags: iphone, google-maps, swift3, uitextfield, google-location-services

In the Google Places AutoComplete Address i am Getting the Predictions via a Text Field but it is not saved in the Text Box How we can Do it in swift/ios

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let indexPath = table1.indexPathForSelectedRow
        let currentCell = table1.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as! UITableViewCell
        print(currentCell.textLabel?.text)
        txtField.text = currentCell.textLabel?.text
        UserAddress = txtField.text
    }
```